# Hadoop second reducer not being called when chaining two jobs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have an hadoop program where I want to chain two jobs such that input -> mapper1 -> reducer1 -> mapper2 -> reducer2 -> output. The first half works fine and I get a correct intermediate output. The problem lies within the second job. In particular, I believe that in the second job the mapper does not call the right reducer for some reason since I get a type mismatch.
Here is the code of the main where I set up the jobs:

```
    //JOB 1
    Path input1 = new Path(otherArgs.get(0));
    Path output1 =new Path("/tempBinaryPath");

    Job job1 = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job1.setJarByClass(BinaryPathRefined.class);
        job1.setJobName("BinaryPathR1");

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, input1);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, output1);

    job1.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    //job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);
    job1.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    job1.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job1.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job1.waitForCompletion(true);


    // JOB 2
    Path input2 = new Path("/tempBinaryPath/part-r-00000");
    Path output2 =new Path(otherArgs.get(1));

    Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2);
        job2.setJarByClass(BinaryPathRefined.class);
        job2.setJobName("BinaryPathR2");

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, input2);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, output2);

    job2.setMapperClass(MyMapper2.class);
    //job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);
    job2.setReducerClass(MyReducer2.class);

    job2.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job2.waitForCompletion(true);
```

The mappers and the reducers are of the form:

```
public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{
...
}

public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{
...
}

public static class MyMapper2 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
...
}

public static class MyReducer2 extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text>{
...
}
```

The first job runs fine, while in the second I get the error:

```
Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call only `setOutputKeyClass` and `setOutputValueClass` Hadoop will assume that both Mapper and Reducer has the same output types. In your case, you should explicitely set what are the types of the output the Mapper produces:

```
job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job2.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```